# Why are the MSA direction needles not oriented to north?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, navigation, approach, iap

Why is it when you look at an MSA the arrows are pointed opposite of where they should be?[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The arrows are referencing the nav cues, not the VORTAC radials, which define the MSA zones.  It’s cut up that way to define the sectors relative to the reference point that you will be flying in e.g. for the second from left MSA symbol, if you’re flying southeast of the HQM VORTAC between a course heading of 230° TO and 350° TO the VORTAC, this is an acceptable MSA for that segment.  I suspect that choice was made because aircrews are going to be approaching the airport from these areas as opposed to departing and their HSIs, OBSs, RMIs, etc are going to be set to track TO the NAVAID at that point.